# what is your preferred twitter api - I use tweepy but can only get 100 tweets

Tags: python, twitter

results = api.search(q='sunny', count=1000)

Although I set up the count to 1000, I still only get 100 which seems to be tweepy's maximum. Which twitter API could provide more tweets?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using a middleman for the twitter API? why not just Twitters API directly yourself?

Comment: Yes, 100 is the maximum number of Tweets available in a single call to the Twitter v1.1 search API. You will need to implement paging in order to get the "next page" of 100 Tweets. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets